# Using tx:annotation-driven prevents Autowiring a bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, osgi, transactional, eclipse-virgo

I'm developing a module on an OSGi application, using Spring MVC and Virgo Webserver.

On my module I have a Controller, that access a Manager, which has a list of handlers that are responsible for handling report generation.

Everything was doing fine until I had to call a transactional method from an external service. Since none of my classes were transactional I had to add the references to the transation manager and `annotation-driven`. Then, my Manager stopped being notified.

I understand that when using `annotation-driven` all my beans must implement a public interface in order for the proxying mechanism to work. And as far as I know, all the classes are (one of them wasn't, but then I changed it).

My configuration files are:

bundle-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="reportManager" class="reportmodule.manager.impl.ReportManagerImpl"/>
<bean id="mvpepReportHandler" class="reportmodule.manager.impl.MVPEPReportHandler"/>
<bean id="reportConfigDao" class="reportmodule.repository.impl.ReportConfigurationHibernateDAOImpl"/>
<bean id="oSGIChangeReportHandler" class="reportmodule.osgi.impl.OSGIChangeReportHandlerImpl"/>
<bean id="reportController"
class="reportmodule.controller.impl.ReportControllerImpl"/>
<bean id="reportControllerHandlerMapping"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings">
<value>/module/reportController/**=reportController</value>
</property>
<property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

and my bundle-osgi.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
xmlns:osgi-compendium="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium
http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi-compendium/spring-osgi-compendium-1.2.xsd">

<osgi:reference id="transactionManager" interface="org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager" />
<osgi:reference id="sessionFactory" interface="org.hibernate.SessionFactory" />
<osgi:reference id="smaCoreUtilService" interface="core.util.service.SmaCoreUtilService" />

<osgi:service ref="reportControllerHandlerMapping"
interface="org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping"
context-class-loader="service-provider"
auto-export="interfaces"/>

<osgi:service interface="reportmodule.api.manager.ReportManager" ref="reportManager" auto-export="interfaces"/>

<osgi:service interface="reportmodule.api.manager.ReportHandler" ref="mvpepReportHandler" auto-export="interfaces"/>

<osgi:service interface="reportmodule.repository.ReportConfigurationDAO" ref="reportConfigDao" auto-export="interfaces"/>

<osgi:service interface="reportmodule.osgi.OSGIChangeReportHandler" ref="oSGIChangeReportHandler" auto-export="interfaces"/>

<osgi:list cardinality="0..N" id="reportHandler" interface="reportmodule.api.manager.ReportHandler" greedy-proxying="true">
<osgi:listener ref="oSGIChangeReportHandler" bind-method="register" unbind-method="unregister"/>    
</osgi:list>

</beans>
```

So, after all the services are being published the oSGIChangeReportHandler.register is called (I'm able to debbug it):

```java
@Service(value="oSGIChangeReportHandler")
public class OSGIChangeReportHandlerImpl implements OSGIChangeReportHandler {

    private ReportManager reportManager;

    /**
     * @param reportManager the reportManager to set
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setReportManager(ReportManager reportManager) {
        this.reportManager = reportManager;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void register(ReportHandler reportHandler, Map properties) {
        reportManager.addReportHandler(reportHandler);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void unregister(ReportHandler reportHandler, Map properties) {
        reportManager.removeReportHandler(reportHandler);
    }


}
```

And although the debugger shows Proxies for both the `reportManager` and `reportHandler` on the `register` method, the debugger does not halts on the `ReportManagerImpl.addReportHandler` method:

```java
@Service(value="reportManager")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class ReportManagerImpl implements ReportManager {

    private ReportConfigurationDAO reportConfigurationDAO;

    private ArrayList<ReportHandler> reportHandlers = new ArrayList<ReportHandler>();

    /**
     * @param reportConfigurationDAO the reportConfigurationDAO to set
     */
    @Autowired
    public void setReportConfigurationDAO(ReportConfigurationDAO reportConfigurationDAO) {
        this.reportConfigurationDAO = reportConfigurationDAO;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public InputStream gerarRelatorio(ReportRequest repoReq) throws NegocioException {
        // Generates the report...
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see reportmodule.api.manager.ReportManager#addReportHandler(reportmodule.api.manager.ReportHandler)
     */
    @Override
    public void addReportHandler(ReportHandler handler) {
        if (handler != null) {
            this.reportHandlers.add(handler);
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see reportmodule.api.manager.ReportManager#removeReportHandler(reportmodule.api.manager.ReportHandler)
     */
    @Override
    public void removeReportHandler(ReportHandler handler) {
        if (handler != null) {
            this.reportHandlers.remove(handler);
        }
    }

}
```

I must stress that when I remove the `tx:annotation-driven` tag from the `bundle-context.xml` file, everything works fine (the `handler` is properly added to the list during startup).

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: Is `reportManager` null in `oSGIChangeReportHandler.register`?

Comment: No! It shows a proxy object on the debugger. But I have solved the problem, the answer is below. Thanks for the comment, tho. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved!

As you can see on my code above, I was defining the beans both via `XML` and `Annotation`, thus every bean was duplicated in runtime. Then, when I added the `tx:annotation-driven` tag the application begun intercepting the wrong bean. It was indeed notifying a bean, but an orphan bean.

Answer (score 2):

Here´s an example working with tx. Look this line:
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

and this on schemaLocation:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd

Source:
http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config.html